# string[] preallocation to prevent using ToString() and save memory

Tags: unity, optimization, memory-efficiency

I have some levels, with enemy waves and two `Text` components for:

Enemies killed, like: "13/57"
Waves passed, like: "68"

On each enemy kill/new wave, I make a `ToString()` call, in order to update these UI components. I already separated `"13"`, `"/"` and `"57"` into different `Text`'s to prevent concatenation.

In early game, there's no overhead, but if the game gets more dynamic in time and there are `30-40` enemies on the screen, `GC` get's mad really quickly. It's not a constant `Update(){ tostring() }` call, but it's noticable, really, especially while rendering.

The game itself is really, really expensive, so I need to optimize what I can.

***The point***

The maximum amount of enemies is `200`, so this is the maximum string that will be made through `ToString()`.

There's no maximum wave, but it's quite hard to get to `500` (late-game).

I made a simple system:

```
private static readonly string[] STRING_NUMBERS;

static MathUtils(){
    STRING_NUMBERS = new string[1000];
    for(int i=0;i<STRING_NUMBERS.Length;i++)
    {
        STRING_NUMBERS[i] = i.ToString();
    }
}

public static string GetStringNumber(int i)
{
    if(i > STRING_NUMBERS.Length - 1)
    {
        return i.ToString();
    } 

    return STRING_NUMBERS[i];
}
```

As you can see, I preallocated `1000` strings: `"0"`, `"1"` ... `"999"`.

If I try to get a higher number, it would `ToString()` anyways.

My question is, would it work? is this worth? Did I forget something?

Comment: Are you sure that the method to get and print a wave and enemies killed are the bottleneck here? Sounds like a simple task for a gc or processor. The performance issues might be more related to the number of enemies on screen?

Comment: Maybe you do not have to update the number of kills and waves for each tick/cycle, instead only update when an "enemy killed"-event or "new wave"-event is fired. And instead of using `ToString()` all the time, you could call it once for each event, and then save the text in a variable, reusing it for drawing.